# Listing annotations in a TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-pde

I have an eclipse plug-in with a search-like function. 
The search-like function identifies statements, which fullfill
some conditions and I want to annotate these statements 
and show this annotations in a `TreeViewer`, just like the 
`SearchView` of eclipse.
(How) can I add this annotations to the Model, in order
to show them in the `TreeViewer`? I want the annotations
to apear in the `TreeViewer` under the corresponding JavaElement

Comment: Search view uses [markers](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm) not annotations and markers are added to resource itself not to Java model. But if you only need to show them in your own view (and not in e.g. code editor) then you don't really need any markers, but can use your own content specific associations and provide them to your viewer like pointed out by @FrancisUpton below.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in your `ContentProvider` associated with the `TreeViewer`, you can set the content to anything you like. You can provide the appropriate styled text (instead of plain text) though the content provider.